# The requested resource is not available, struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, http-status-code-404

I am new to struts, I keep having having this error when trying to run a page :

[image]

My project structure :[image]

web.xml :

[image]

struts.xml :

[image]

Any help would be apprectiated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it to work by removing and adding some jars in the lib folder :

[image]